# Incorrect Syntax Error "JOIN" in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel, t-sql

I'm trying to learn VBA Script specifically connecting to SQL and pulling a few account details. However, I'm getting a syntax error "Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'Join'. Could you help me find the syntax error.

```
        strQuery = "" _
                        & "DECLARE @Perns TABLE(Id INT)" _
                        & " INSERT INTO @Perns (Id)" _
                        & " SELECT 4098 " _
                        & " SELECT ddm.FirstName, ddm.LastName, am.alias AS Alias, ddm.PersonnelNbr AS N'Pern#', nam.parent_OU_DN, gc.PersonGroupDesc AS N'AccManNG Status' " _
                        & " FROM @Perns AS p" _
                        & "LEFT OUTER JOIN [Accmanng].[dbo].[directory_data_master] ddm ON p.Id=ddm.PersonnelNbr" _
                        & "LEFT OUTER JOIN [Accmanng].[dbo].[alias_master] am ON am.alias_id = ddm.alias_id" _
                        & "LEFT OUTER JOIN [Accmanng].[dbo].[network_account_master] nam ON AM.alias_id = nam.alias_id" _
                        & "LEFT OUTER JOIN [Accmanng].[dbo].[dim_groupcode] gc ON ddm.PersonGroupCode=gc.PersonGroupCode " _
                        & "WHERE ddm.PersonnelNbr in ( SELECT Id FROM @perns)"


    rst.Open strQuery, ConnectString


    Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
```

Comment: What is `N'Pern#'` and `N'AccManNG Status'`?

Comment: Also shouldn't there be a space before `LEFT` ?

Comment: It changes the Column Names, it's just making it easier to read. That way when we copy with Headers its already labeled.

Comment: That was it, There was a space before LEFT.

Comment: Looks to me like you've got your answer, but as an extra: I'd change the first join to an INNER join and then you could remove the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print out your code.  About 19 times out of 20 that makes the error obvious.

The first few lines of your code are:

```
DECLARE @Perns TABLE(Id INT)
INSERT INTO @Perns (Id)
 SELECT 4098 
 SELECT ddm.FirstName, ddm.LastName, am.alias AS Alias, ddm.PersonnelNbr AS N'Pern#', nam.parent_OU_DN, gc.PersonGroupDesc AS N'AccManNG Status' 

. . .
```

This is not valid SQL:

```
SELECT 4098 SELECT ddm.FirstName
```

Comment: beat me to it! Besides the extra select there are tons of spacing issues too.

Comment: Could you elaborate how this wouldn't be a valid statement.

If I have INSERT INTO Perns (ID) and use the Select to store those variables, later calling it using the Second select and saying where it's coming from. For Example FROM Perns AS P thus then creating the outer joins.

Comment: @RyanWilliamWest . . . I think it is pretty basic why `SELECT 4098 SELECT ddm.FirstName` is not valid SQL.  A `SELECT` statement only has one `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the **space** before the JOIN clause

```
      strQuery = "" _
                    & "DECLARE @Perns TABLE(Id INT)" _
                    & " INSERT INTO @Perns (Id)" _
                    & " SELECT 4098 " _
                    & " SELECT ddm.FirstName, ddm.LastName, am.alias AS Alias, ddm.PersonnelNbr AS N'Pern#', nam.parent_OU_DN, gc.PersonGroupDesc AS N'AccManNG Status' " _
                    & " FROM @Perns AS p" _
                    & " LEFT OUTER JOIN [Accmanng].[dbo].[directory_data_master] ddm ON p.Id=ddm.PersonnelNbr" _
                    & " LEFT OUTER JOIN [Accmanng].[dbo].[alias_master] am ON am.alias_id = ddm.alias_id" _
                    & " LEFT OUTER JOIN [Accmanng].[dbo].[network_account_master] nam ON AM.alias_id = nam.alias_id" _
                    & " LEFT OUTER JOIN [Accmanng].[dbo].[dim_groupcode] gc ON ddm.PersonGroupCode=gc.PersonGroupCode " _
                    & " WHERE ddm.PersonnelNbr in ( SELECT Id FROM @perns)"
```

EDIT: Also Gordon caught some more issues. I'm pretty sure the error you get is because of the space near join.